# Как скачать файл, который лежит в корне с проектом React или Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Предположим файл лежит в src/assets/file.html как его скачать через href я пробовал не скачивается, просто не реагирует, через window location тоже пробовал, там ссылка начинается с file это что-то вроде типа файла, в общем ситуация вроде прстая, но что-то никак, по сути мне нужно скачать тот самый html на котором я нахожусь

Answer (score 0):

То что ты хочешь сделать точно не будет работать. Билды Вебпака и Бабеля выглядят совсем по другому. Чтобы посмотреть например что будет в продакшене запусти npm run build и посмотри что сбилдят Вебпак и Бабель.

Comment: что такое Билды Бабеля?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: На сервере код страницы не лежит в файлах .jsx и js, разложенным по папкам как в твоем редакторе кода.
Для того чтобы подготовить код для сервера, код обрабатывается специальными модулями такими как Вебпак и Бабель. Они делают набора файлов для проекта и эти файлы совсем не такие как твои.
Чтобы посмотреть что будет лежать на твоем веб-сервере запусти команду npm run build в твоем терминале. У тебя появится папка build. В этой папке будет лежать то, что будет выложено на сервер.